# Setting devise user type or role at sign-up using radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails application with a devise `user` model. `user` has the attributes `tutor:boolean` and `student:boolean` to define the type (or role) of the user as either a tutor or student. I would like to include radio buttons on the sign-up form to select to create account as either a tutor or a student.

In the devise form I added:

```
<%= f.radio_button :role, "student" %>
<%= f.label :student, "Student" %>
<%= f.radio_button :role, "tutor" %>
<%= f.label :tutor, "Tutor" %>
```

Then in the `ApplicationController` I added

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:role])
end
```

in order to allow `params[:user][:role]` through.

The idea was, I would be able to use this param and a bit of logic (`student: true, if: :role_is_student` type thing) in the model to create a new `user` object with the proper attributes for `student` and `tutor`.

However, it seems that I had the wrong idea with how the devise `form_with` works as it won't even load giving me

```
NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new
undefined method `role' for #<User id: nil...>
```

I realize that the form is making a post request to create the user right away so I need to implement the logic to set the proper attribute (`student` or `tutor`) in the form itself.

Any help on the best way to do this would be great! Thanks.